# How can we dynamically change font color in textarea using Angular/jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, textarea

How can we dynamically change font color in textarea having several colora for different words using Angular/jQuery/JavaScript? Is there any plugin already available for this? Found some of the plugins on Google but they are all for syntax highlighting/coloring. Which takes a specific language and highlights.

I need to pass multiple lists and the text area should change color of matching words from list 1 to blue, list 2 words to green and so on.

Suppose I have two lists of words:

```
var list1 = ['apple', 'banana'];
var list2 = ['house', 'apartment'];
```

I would like to have all the words in list1 with one colour and all the words in list2 with another colour.

Comment: Added a brief example and clarified the question

Answer (score 0):

> You can't change color words in textarea, but you can use
>   `contenteditable` attribute to change content text of element (like
>   div, p, span). To do this work you can use javascript plugin, but if
>   you want to create it, you can use this code. For this purpose, you
>   need to get any word in text.Then check that if target word is in SQL
>   statement highlight it.

```js
$("#editor").on("keydown keyup", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32){
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").trim();
        var word = text.split(" ");
        var newHTML = "";

        $.each(word, function(index, value){
            switch(value.toUpperCase()){
                case "SELECT":
                case "FROM":
                case "WHERE":
                case "LIKE":
                case "BETWEEN":
                case "NOT LIKE":
                case "FALSE":
                case "NULL":
                case "FROM":
                case "TRUE":
                case "NOT IN":
                    newHTML += "<span class='statement'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
                    break;
                default: 
                    newHTML += "<span class='other'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
            }
        });
       $(this).html(newHTML);
        
        //// Set cursor postion to end of text
        var child = $(this).children();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        $(this)[0].focus(); 
    }
});
```

```css
#editor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
  
.statement {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think my question was little misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think my question was little misleading. I need something like an editor (eg. notepad++)where font color changes when user types a specific keyword. eg when I enter 'select * from tab' then the keywords 'select' and 'from' should change color. This should happen while typing itself inside a text area.

Comment: I tried with contenteditable div but there are many issues with this. Major one is cursor always jumps to the end of line when there are <span> tags inside the div.

Comment: hmmm yupp .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the color CSS attribute of your `textarea`. If you have a `textarea` with the `id` of `foo`, then you can change its font color like this:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "red";
```

If you need to change the font `color` of all your `textareas`, then you will need to gather them and change their `color`

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (var index in textareas) {
    textareas[index].style.color = "red";
}
```

This is how you do it with plain Javascript. With jQuery you can do it like this in case of the `id` of `foo`

```
$("#foo").css("color", "red");
```

and for all `textareas`

```
$("textarea").css("color", "red");
```